# Why is my output always 0.00?

Tags: c++, function, class

```
// The output for cubic yards is always 0.00

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Road
{
public:
    void set_road_width(double width);
    void set_road_length(double length);
    void set_road_depth(double depth);
    double asphalt_required();
private:
    double roadDepth;
    double roadWidth;
    double roadLength;
    double roadAsphalt;
};

int main()
{
    Road width, length, depth, asphalt, output;
    double inputWidth = 0.0, inputLength = 0.0, inputDepth = 0.0;


    cout << "Enter the width of the road in miles: ";
    cin  >> inputWidth;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter the length of the road in miles: ";
    cin  >> inputLength;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter the depth of the road in inches: ";
    cin  >> inputDepth;
    cout << endl;


    width.set_road_width(inputWidth);
    length.set_road_length(inputLength);
    depth.set_road_depth(inputDepth);
    asphalt.asphalt_required();


    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
    cout.precision(2);


    cout << "The width of the road is: " << inputWidth << " mile(s)" << endl;
    cout << "The length of the road is: " << inputLength << " mile(s)" << endl;
    cout << "The depth of the road is: " << inputDepth << " inch(es)" << endl;  
    cout << "Asphalt required: " << output.asphalt_required() << " cubic yard(s)" << endl;

    return 0;
}

void Road::set_road_width(double width)
{
    roadWidth = width;
}

void Road::set_road_length(double length)
{
    roadLength = length;
}

void Road::set_road_depth(double depth)
{
    roadDepth = depth;
}

double Road::asphalt_required()
{
    double widthIntoYards = 0.0, lengthIntoYards = 0.0, depthIntoYards = 0.0, yardConversionFactor = 0.333;

    widthIntoYards = ((roadWidth * 5280.00) * yardConversionFactor);
    lengthIntoYards = ((roadLength * 5280.00) * yardConversionFactor);
    depthIntoYards = ((roadDepth / 12.00) * yardConversionFactor);

    roadAsphalt = (widthIntoYards * lengthIntoYards * depthIntoYards);

    return(roadAsphalt);
}
```

The output is always 0.00. I think it has something to do with the asphalt_required() function or with the line cout << "Asphalt required: " << output.asphalt_required() << "cubic yard(s)" << endl; Now I'm just writing because Stack Overflow says that I need to add some more context, perhaps to balance out the code.

Comment: `Road width, length, depth, asphalt, output;` this does not make sense to me.  You have 5 roads called `width`, `length`, `depth`, `asphalt` and `output`?  I'm assuming you meant to only have one road with the different properties.

Comment: Output is always `0.0` because you have assigned it to that value, and you are not changing it anywhere. You should look at the execution using a debugger, and you will see the problem.

Comment: I fixed the Road class. I made one Road object, road, and it works. Thanks for all the responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need just one single `road`:

```
int main()
{
    Road road;
    double inputWidth = 0.0, inputLength = 0.0, inputDepth = 0.0;


    cout << "Enter the width of the road in miles: ";
    cin  >> inputWidth;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter the length of the road in miles: ";
    cin  >> inputLength;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter the depth of the road in inches: ";
    cin  >> inputDepth;
    cout << endl;


    road.set_road_width(inputWidth);
    road.set_road_length(inputLength);
    road.set_road_depth(inputDepth);
    road.asphalt_required();


    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
    cout.precision(2);


    cout << "The width of the road is: " << inputWidth << " mile(s)" << endl;
    cout << "The length of the road is: " << inputLength << " mile(s)" << endl;
    cout << "The depth of the road is: " << inputDepth << " inch(es)" << endl;
    cout << "Asphalt required: " << road.asphalt_required() << " cubic yard(s)" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that problem is here:

```
Road width, length, depth, asphalt, output;

/// Some code

width.set_road_width(inputWidth);
length.set_road_length(inputLength);
depth.set_road_depth(inputDepth);
asphalt.asphalt_required();
```

and how it could be

```
Road output;

/// Some code

output.set_road_width(inputWidth);
output.set_road_length(inputLength);
output.set_road_depth(inputDepth);
output.asphalt_required();
```

That would help you.

This is because you create one instance of class where you already have everything for your calculations. In this situation that might be better to have everything you need in your constructor, like this:

```
class Road
{
public:
   Road(double width, double length, double depth)
   double asphalt_required();
private:
   double roadDepth;
   double roadWidth;
   double roadLength;
   double roadAsphalt;
};

Road::Road(double width, double length, double depth)
 : roadDepth(depth)
 , roadWidth(width)
 , roadLength(length) {
}

/// Other code...
```

This is better, because it could also prevent you from such errors. Everything that you would need to do is do some modification

```
double inputWidth = 0.0, inputLength = 0.0, inputDepth = 0.0;

/// Here we got all needed values...

Road output(inputWidth, inputLength, inputDepth);
output.asphalt_required();

/// And then output...
```

Answer (score 1):

You never do anything with `output` other than construct it and print its `asphalt_required()`.  This is why it prints zero: you never actually modify `output` in any way!

Beyond that, you may want to think about why you construct so many `Road` instances.  It seems like there should be only one.  As it stands, you have five `Road`s: three are one-dimensional and two are zero-dimensional.